# Add related data to Elasticsearch (architectural issue)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an `index` in `Elasticsearch` that stores mutations for each dataset:

```
    [{
      _index: "dataset_mutations#32345",
      _type: "mutation",
      start: "2344",
      end: "2345",
      ...
    }, 
    {
      _index: "dataset_mutations#32345",
      _type: "mutation",
      start: "22440",
      end: "22441", 
      ...
    },
    ...]
```

Where `#32345` is the dataset number. Now I want to store also all of the genes of the dataset. I could create a separate index for it, but then because I have many datasets, all of their `dataset_mutations` and `gene` indexes would be mixed up. It does not seem organized to me but I am not sure, very new to it. For me it seems that to somehow add another `type` for the same dataset `index` would be better. However, the database is all about `mutations` and it is encoded in the name of the index itself as can be seen. So, semantically it would be wrong to include `gene` `type` under the `dataset_mutations` index. Another idea is to restructure the database to have `dataset` index and then two types `mutation` and `gene`. The problem is that `gene` - level data is very small compared to `mutation` data and so it looks like restructuring for the sake of minor semantic expansion. What would you propose using the best practices here?

Comment: Does `gene` altogether hold different type of data than `mutation`? Is there any relation between `gene` and `mutation`? What is the maximum number of datasets?

Comment: Yes, `gene` holds the data that is altogether different. The only relation between `gene` and `mutation` is that both of them are from a certain dataset. Max number of datasets is around 1000 at the moment, but it may actually be unbounded number long term.

Comment: Index per data set would lead to explode the number of indexes in a cluster. Having said if you never would have to query both `gene` and `mutation` together then I would suggest you to have to indexes `mutation` and `gene` with `dataset` as a field in both the indexes. If you would have to jointly query both of them then I would suggest you second approach to have one index say `dataset` and two types 'gene' and `mutation`.